# Java custom input output stream

Tags: java, stream

I need a stream (or something) to which i can write and read using streams, both from program in Java, here is some example:

```
CustomStream stream = new CustomStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream.getInputStream());
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(stream.getOutputStream());

pw.println("Hello");
pw.println("World");

System.out.println(reader.readLine()); //Hello
System.out.println(reader.readLine()); //World
```

Guess this is pretty retarded example, but is there any way to do it, except implementing all methods from abstract Stream class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a Java `Pipe` object

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html

The interface is close to what you suggest above.  Note that the `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` classes will make the pipe easier to interface with.

For some applications, the `CircularBuffer` class may suffice and save on a little typing, but it essentially does the same thing.